# How can I manipulate the interactive toolbar box of a plotl- plot in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly

How can I manipulate the **toolbar** (I am not sure whether name is correct?! see the [image: pic].) of a plot which is generated by `plotly` package in shiny?
that is my code in the `server` side:

```
 plot_ly(pl.d, x = ~x, y = ~y1, type = 'bar', name = colnames(dataset())[2], marker = list(color = "#26478A"),
            height=800) %>%
      add_trace(y = ~y2, name = colnames(dataset())[3], marker = list(color = "#FF6600")) %>%
      add_trace(y = ~y3, name = colnames(dataset())[4], marker = list(color = "#7E182F")) %>%
      layout("title" = colnames(d.plot)[1],
             xaxis = list(title = "", tickangle = 65,tickfont  = list(family= "Arial",size = 14),
                          margin = m
                          ), 
             yaxis = list(title = "",ticksuffix = "%"),
             barmode = 'group'
            # autosize = F, width = 500, height = 500,,margin = m
             )
```

Comment: I think it's called modebar.

Comment: https://plot.ly/javascript/configuration-options/#remove-modebar-buttons

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you want to modify in the tool bar but if you wanted to take some items away you can use `config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = list("lasso2d","hoverClosestCartesian",                                                                        "hoverCompareCartesian","select2d"))` At least for ggplotly this is the case but I'm pretty sure you can use this with the plotly function as well.